# Check if the number is under 0 and 25

Tags: c#, .net

I code my upcoming task and it is a bingo game. I have made the most of the code. I want to check if the numbers are under 0 or over 25. If the numbers are under or over, I want to warn the user and tell the user to resubmit.

I would like some advice on how to solve with my code. Right now, I only warn if the user types letters.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] lottonumbers = new int[10];

        Random number = new Random();
        int lottonumber = number.Next(1, 25);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottonumber);

        bool match = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Hi and welcome to Bingo!");

        for (int i = 0; i < lottonumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter 10 bingo numbers.Only numbers between 1 - 25 are valid!");
            int element = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out element))
            {
                lottonumbers[i] = element;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No letters are valid, only numbers(integers).");
                --i;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lottonumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lottonumbers[i] == lottonumber)
            {
                match = true;
            }
        }

        if (match == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bingo number {0} matched! You got Bingo!", lottonumber);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was no bingo!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before adding the number (element) to your lottonumbers array apply a check for a value lower than 1 or higher than 25. By the way. The second parameter to Random.Next is excluded from the values returned by the method (You never get 25)

Comment: do you mean something like this: if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out element))
                {
                    if (element < 0 || element > 25)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The number is under 1 or over 25");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lottonumbers[i] = element;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No letters are valid, only numbers(integers).");
                    --i;
           }
 }

Comment: Yes, but you don't need again to TryParse the input. You have already it in the element integer. Just the if is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question with the code below.
Do not know if it's right or smart solution. Maybe you can give me feedback.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < lottonumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter 10 bingo numbers.Only numbers between 1 - 25 are valid!");
            int element = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out element))
            {
                if (element >= 1 && element <= 25) 
                {
                    lottonumbers[i] = element;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Endast siffror siffror mellan 1 och 25 är tillåtna, mata igen");
                    --i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No letters are valid, only numbers(integers).");
                --i;
            }
        }
```

The full code is

```
 int[] lottonumbers = new int[10];

        Random number = new Random();
        int lottonumber = number.Next(1, 26);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", lottonumber);

        bool match = false;

        Console.WriteLine("Hi and welcome to Bingo!");

        for (int i = 0; i < lottonumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter 10 bingo numbers.Only numbers between 1 - 25 are valid!");
            int element = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out element))
            {
                if (element >= 1 && element <= 25) 
                {
                    lottonumbers[i] = element;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only numbers between 1 and 25 are valid, write again");
                    --i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No letters are valid, only numbers(integers).");
                --i;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < lottonumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lottonumbers[i] == lottonumber)
            {
                match = true;
            }
        }

        if (match == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bingo number {0} matched! You got Bingo!", lottonumber);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was no bingo!");
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```